# Use quote after command echo

Tags: bash

I came across a small script:

```
$ for i in *.sh; do echo "$i"; done
name with space.sh
name_with_dash.sh
```

When I unquoted `$i`, it produces the same result.

```
$ for i in *.sh; do echo $i; done
name with space.sh
name_with_dash.sh
```

I can see how `"$i"` might need to be quoted for old-fashioned commands like `test [ ]`, `cd`, or `rm`. Is it necessary to use quotes with `echo`, too?

Comment: Try the quoted and unquoted versions with a name that has two or more *consecutive* spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll see a difference if a filename contains multiple consecutive spaces:

```
touch "name with   multiple spaces.sh"
```

With the quotes it will correctly echo:

```
name with   multiple spaces.sh
```

Without the quotes it will combine all the spaces, displaying an incorrect filename:

```
name with multiple spaces.sh
```

The quotes prevent word-splitting, which parses the result of the variable expansion as words separated by whitespace (you can change the delimiter characters by setting the `IFS` variable).

You'll rarely go wrong if you always quote your variables. You should only use the variable unquoted when you specifically *need* word splitting or wildcard expansions.

Comment: Some other situations where unquoted variables will cause trouble: if they contain tabs, linefeeds, or wildcards. Add a file named "name?with*.sh" to the list above and retry the test.